# Angular 10 differential loading continues generating ES5 bundle when disabled

Tags: angular

In my Angular 10 project, I want to support modern browsers only. And for that purpose I've changed my configuration like this:

```
Angular: 10.2.0
Node.js: v14
```

**.browserslistrc**

```
supports es6-module
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "lib": [
            "es2019",
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunetely, it is still generating ES5 bundle. How can I solve this?

Comment: Upgrade your version of Angular ?

Comment: Not possible for now.